# iOS segmented control with a little triangle on top

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I draw a little triangle above the selected item in a `UISegmentedControl`? Does anyone know an open-source than extends it?
(if not - pointers of how to do it)

Design should look like (this is in the bottom of the screen)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a native way to do that. You can either find a library that allows for it, but you can do it yourself fairly easily, which I recommend.

I can think of a few out of the box ways to approach it, here at the two I think worth mentioning off the bat:

1) Use UISegmentedControl with images. Make the segmented controller have a height that includes the triangle, and have an image for selected and normal states that shows what you want. The Normal states would have a rectangle of transparency on top, as wide as the entire image and as tall as the triangle. The selected image would include the triangle. Both images should end up the same width and height.

2) Subclass UISegmentedControl and do some custom drawing in `drawRect:`. You could draw the triangle outside (above) the bounds of the segmented controller, make sure to set the segmented controller's `clipToBounds` property to NO, as well as its `layer`'s `masksToBounds` property.

If you'd like more help, or some other suggestions, just ask.

Comment: thanks for the tips. no. 1 I think is not an option because I want to have a real label in it, and image is not fun.
I tried to avoid rolling my own with DrawRect - it is time consuming but I guess this is the only option